# tablesorter filter widget : extend tablesorter-infoOnly behavior with selector

Tags: jquery, filter, css-selectors, tablesorter

We have a table with rows of data and rows of presentation as category.

We can use  tablesorter-infoOnly class for ignoring these presentation rows. But when filtering we would like that these rows to be hidden if they do not have non hidden data sibling rows.

It seems we cannot use jquery selector on the property cssInfoBlock. Is there another way to  achieve this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The `tablesorter-infoOnly` class is meant to only be used on a `<tbody>` element.

If you want have rows attached to a parent, and ignored for sorting, then use the `tablesorter-childRow` class name (see [`cssChildRow` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#csschildrow)) on the `tr`. To hide and toggle these rows, you'll need to add custom coding and css.

If you're still stuck, please provide a demo (modify [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/)) so that I may be able to better help you.